# Buttons created in HTML5 that will fit any screen resoution

Tags: css

I am creating a web site for a friend and is strictly practice for me.  So far I have got the banner w/ logo to fit any screen, but now I am adding buttons so a user can navigate through out the site. When zooming in or out the buttons go all over the place. I am using an external CSS sheet to help format my HTML. Here is my CSS3 code

```
 /* W & W Hydrographics, LLC. */
    /* Robert W. Anderson HTML 5.0 */

.mybutton {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font: bold 30px/35px Arial, sans-serif;

    box-shadow:#000 4px 4px 5px;
}


/* Our Gallery */
.gallery {
    position:absolute;
    left:5%;
    top:5%;
    color: #F5DA62;
    background: #3F403D;

}
/* Available Patterns */
.patterns {
    position:absolute;
    left:300px;
    top:230px;
    color: #F5DA62;
    background: #3F403D;

}
/* Contact Us */
.contact {
    position:absolute;
    left:650px;
    top:230px;
    color: #515151;
    color: #F5DA62;
    background: #3F403D;
}

body {
    background-size: 100%

}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to create a responsive design?

Comment: My advice is. Just learn the [BOOTSTRAP](http://getbootstrap.com/). Then you can create using much better website for your friend. Of course, you have to add your css also. So, Just go ahead with [BOOTSTRAP](http://getbootstrap.com/). Happy journey.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS3 to find the width of the screen and adjust the size of the buttons(again, according to the size).Here is a small explanation of an example just so you can unserstand.Suppose I had a button with id #button with a 300px width like this-

```
#button{
 width:300px;
       }
```

If i wanted to change the width to 100px in mobiles(mobiles have average width 470px;) I can do it like this-

```
@media (max-width: 470px) {
 #button{
 width:300px;
       }
                           }
```

You can use the same logic to adjust size of other elements and even multiple elements at the same time like this-

```
   @media (max-width: 470px) {
   #button{
   width:300px;
       }
   #button2{
   width:300px;
       }
   #someelement{
   color:#C30;
       }

                               }
```

If you didnt understand a part of my answer, just comment. I am free to answer more doubts.